# Android: Compilation Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-recyclerview

I am facing the following error:

```
Error:(89, 39) error: incomparable types: CAP#1 and int  
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:  
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?Note: Some input files use unchecked or   unsafe operations.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.  
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

My Gradle File looks like below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "wishlist.oj.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
}
```

The error is coming from My Recycler View Adaptor File which just inflates the multpile textviews into recycler view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

### For Good Practice

At first enable `multiDexEnabled` ,Then upgrade your `support:recyclerview` ,`support:appcompat` ,`support:cardview` version

> The Android plugin for Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools
>   21.1 and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration. Make sure you update the Android SDK Build Tools tools and the Android
>   Support Repository to the latest version using the SDK Manager before
>   attempting to configure your app for multidex.

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project. In particular you need to perform the following steps:

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
     android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            ...

            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"
      compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
     }
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync** Your Project

Comment: same error persists.. what changes i need to do in android manifest file?

Comment: @ojas same logcat returns ??

Comment: @ojas you can set `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` Whats your classpath ?

Comment: using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` ?

Comment: where should i write classpath. I cant write this in dependencies.
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" was not helpful....my gradle version : 2.2.1 .. android plugin version:1.2.2 ... do i need to update anything?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: I have applied your solution...along with above erros new error came: Note: C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\WishList\app\src\main\java\oj\app\home\AdaptorDrawer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add.

```
android:{
 lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

}
```